# Perl - Scanning CSV files for rows that match user-specified criteria?

Tags: perl

I am trying to write/learn a simple Perl parser for some CSV files that I have and I need some help.

In a directory I have a series of date-indexed CSV files in the form of Text-Date.csv.  The date is in the form of Month-DD-YYYY (ex., January-07-2011).  For each weekday there is a CSV file generated.

The Perl script should open each file look for a particular row that matches a user-entered criteria and return that row.  Each row is stock price data with different stocks in different rows.  What the script should do is return the price of a particular stock (ex., IBM) across all dates that CSVs are generated.

I have the parser working for a specific CSV/date that I choose, but I want to be able to pluck out the row in all CSVs.  Also when I print the IBM price for each dated CSV I want to display the date next to the price (ex., January-07-2011 IBM 147.93).

Can you help me get this done?

Comment: How simple is the pattern you're matching? Sounds like a simple grep will do everything you want here.

Comment: What's the question you're mentioning in the title? You are certain to get constructive answers if you [post your code and point out the difficulties you are having with it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4650787/edit).

Comment: I fixed using opendir and foreach...

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to crawl a bunch of files and run some function on each one, you probably want [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html). To parse CSV, definitely use [Text::xSV](http://search.cpan.org/~tilly/Text-xSV-0.21/lib/Text/xSV.pm) and not a custom parser. There is more to parsing CSV than calling split(",").

Comment: but still better use Text::CSV;

Comment: Really? I haven't done CSV parsing in over a year, but it seemed to me that xSV was a bit better. Probably either one is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To parse CSV files, use the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) module.

It is more complex to decide how you are going to apply the criteria - you'll need to determine what the user specifies and work out how to translate that into Perl code that evaluates the condition correctly.